# Cannot access Bintray account

Tags: bintray

I apologize if this is off-topic, but this is the only public support channel for Bintray OSS that I could find. I'm hoping someone from JFrog monitors this tag.

I opted into the Bintray beta look, and now I can no longer access any of my or my organization's repositories. I log in, I click the repo link, and it hangs on a JFrog logo. If I refresh the page or navigate back, I'm no longer signed in. When logged in, I have no option to switch back to the old look (the option is only available on repository views, which I cannot access while logged in; if I switch while not logged in, the setting reverts back to beta after login).

At this point, my account is effectively disabled. I would appreciate any help by the JFrog/Bintray team. Or, perhaps someone can point me to a better resource for getting Bintray support for an OSS account.

Comment: Sorry, couldn't reproduce the issue with my Bintray account.

Comment: @royg I'm curious... Do you log in with GitHub or another social provider, or do you have specific credentials for Bintray?

Comment: with my credentials, and you?

Comment: @Royg With my GitHub account. Could be something broken with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried it again, and it's working now. Guessing they fixed the glitch in the beta site. But I switched back to the old one just to be safe.

Answer (score 0):

If you are logged in you can use the bookmarkable link to access the repositories or packages, you might see the `class=new-look-button` on that page. Also check the DOM, you might be able to "click" the button from the browser console.

Bookmarable example:
`https://bintray.com/beta/#/:organization_name/:repo_name?tab=packages`

Comment: No, sorry. I can already go to links like that. The problem is that when I do, the page itself doesn't display. That's the page that only displays the JFrog logo. Furthermore, it seems to log me out of my account whenever I attempt to load those URLs.

Comment: I have tried inspecting the page and notice that a particular fetch request results in a 401, which is probably what keeps the page from loading. I suspect that my auth token is getting lost before displaying the page.

Comment: If you get 401, then I would send a ticket to Bintray support, I think they can solve it for you.